# How To Right Align a field In RTF template

Tags: oracle, oracle-xml-publisher

I am using XML Publisher report(RTF template) and the output format as Excel. When my output opens in Excel all numeric values are left aligned. I want numeric values to be Right aligned.. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard right align button in Word.